# Not able to run shell script from a browser in Mac

Tags: macos, shell, browser, terminal

I need to run a .sh file from test.html on Mac but not able to do so, whereas the same script works for Windows browser

I have a test.html file which calls another php file and in the php file I am calling the .sh file

test.html:

```
<html>


<form action="Sample1.php" method="post">
<select name= "AutomationEnv">
  <option value= "abc" >option1</option>
  <option value= "xyz" >option2</option>
</select>
</P>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="RUN">

</form>
</html>

Sample1.php:
<?php

$output = file_get_contents("run.sh");
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

        $proc = popen($output, 'r');
        echo '<pre>';
        while (!feof($proc))
        {
            echo fread($proc, 4096);
            @ flush();
        }
        echo '</pre>';

?>
```

On clicking the run button in the browser it should execute run.sh file and print the output on the browser. This code is working on chrome for windows but not working on chrome/safari for mac.

Comment: wherre is the shell located?

Comment: all files are in the same directory.